# angularjs - need help for delayed search directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/graphicsxp/QA4Fa/2/

I'm triying to create a directive for searching. Basically it's just a textbox that detects user input and after a 1 second delay, a search method is called.

It's not working yet and I'm having two issues.

First, why is the filterCriteria not updated in the span when user inputs text  ?

Second, the watch on filterCriteria is triggered at page loading but not when text is entered in the textbox.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">   
  <delayed-search ng-model="filterCriteria"></delayed-search>
   <span>filter criteria is : {{filterCriteria}}</span>
</div>

angular.module('myApp', []).directive("delayedSearch", ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: '<input type="text"  />',
    scope: {
        filterCriteria : '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
        var timer = false;
        $scope.$watch('filterCriteria', function () {
            if (timer) {
                $timeout.cancel(timer);
            }
            timer = $timeout(function () {
                alert('timeout expired');
            }, 1000)
        });
    }
}
}]).controller('myController', function($scope){  });
```

Comment: As an alternate approach, take a look at this answer, which provides a directive that allows you to put a delay on ngChange: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121460/angular-directive-encapsulating-a-delay-for-ng-change/21420441#21420441. Use ngChange to call the search method with an ngDelay of 1s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First, why is the filterCriteria not updated in the span when user inputs text ?

Your scope is wrong, it should be `scope: { ngModel : '=' },`, and your template should be `template: '<input type="text" ng-model="ngModel" />`.

> Second, the watch on filterCriteria is triggered at page loading but not when text is entered in the textbox.

Same as the first problem, you should be watching `ngModel`.

Also, you don't need the overhead of a controller for this, you can get away with just using the link function.  Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QA4Fa/3/

Answer (score 3):

```
You should NOT use a controller with a directive ( until you understand it ! ) .
```

A controller in a directive is meant for directive to directive communication (I wish they had named it something else!).

@Langdon got it right.. But here is another implementation of the same. Note that in both the answer's the controller is missing.

http://jsfiddle.net/QA4Fa/4/

Comment: nice one ! and thanks for the advice, it's very useful (i'm still learning angular). I'll mark Langdon's reply as answer though as he was first to reply. Thanks for helping.