# ng-change to only execute after a user has stopped typing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I am developing a search option for my web app written in angularjs. The situation now is the following: a request to the backend server is fired with ng-change every time something is typed into the search field, this can lead to an unneccessary amount of calls to the backend..

What is a good way of limiting the amount of search request? I'm thinking of something that waits until the user has stopped typing and then sends the request.

Answer (score 0):

I posted an answer in [angular directive encapsulating a delay for ng-change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121460/angular-directive-encapsulating-a-delay-for-ng-change/21122939#21122939) that works. It simplify the search by using a directive.

If you don't like to use a delayed search, you can write your search code on blur of your input box.