# Angular js stop previous http request with ng-change

Tags: angularjs

Trying to implement a search field with angular js.

Everytime the input value changes, it will call a method to fetch the query results.

However its very slow because for every char, it will call the method once. My input search box as below

```
<input type="text" name="term" ng-model="term" ng-change="run_filter()"/>
```

My function

```
$scope.do_filter = function() {
    $scope.items = [];
    var canceler;
    term = $scope.term;
    if (canceler) canceler.resolve();
    canceler = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/search/do_search',
        params: {
            term: term
        },
        timeout: canceler.promise
    }).success(function(result) {
        if (result.items != null) {
            $scope.items = result.items;
            $scope.success = true;
        } else {
            $scope.success = false;
        }
        $scope.loading = false;
    });
}
```

But it doesnt seem to work. When I look at the network, the first request is not cancelled when the second request is submitted.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this awesome directive by @Doug R which adds a delay to ng-change.

This totally saved my day because we have some very fast typers at my office.
This will only fire after a certain amount of typing inactivity (300 - 500ms are a good value to start with)

[Delayed ng-change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121460/angular-directive-encapsulating-a-delay-for-ng-change/21420441#comment33368400_21420441)

Another way would be to react with ng-blur or force the user to press RETURN to update the list.