# How can I make angularjs ngChange handler be called only when user finishes typing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change, angular-ngmodel

I have an `input` field, where I want to apply the variant of `ngChange`.

The `input` field is sort of binding with an ajax call, when user changes the input, the server side will process the data, however, I don't wanna make the call too often.

Say the user wanna input a really string, I want the call be made only after user finishes the word he is about to type. 
Nevertheless, I don't wanna use event such as blur. What would be a better way to implement this, rather than `setTimeout`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22158063/angular-ngchange-variant-when-user-finishes-typing

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Use `ng-model-options` in Angular > 1.3

```
 <input type="text"
         ng-model="vm.searchTerm"
         ng-change="vm.search(vm.searchTerm)"
         ng-model-options="{debounce: 750}" />
```

Without `ng-model-options` -- In markup:

```
<input ng-change="inputChanged()">
```

In your backing controller/scope

```
var inputChangedPromise;
$scope.inputChanged = function(){
    if(inputChangedPromise){
        $timeout.cancel(inputChangedPromise);
    }
    inputChangedPromise = $timeout(taskToDo,1000);
}
```

Then your `taskToDo` will only run after 1000ms of no changes.

Comment: i tried this solution, but i am getting it immediately. can you tell me why ?here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NHYx0efhLkeFDqMFwCFw?p=preview)

Comment: `ng-model-options` is only available after angular 1.3

Comment: Thank you so much ... :)

Comment: I Love ya'll...for real <3

Answer (score 38):

As of Angular 1.3, you could use Angular ng-model-options directive

```
<input ng-change="inputChanged()" ng-model-options="{debounce:1000}">
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26356084/1397994

Comment: i tried this solution, but i am getting it immediately. can you tell me why ?here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NHYx0efhLkeFDqMFwCFw?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Write your own directive- this will only run the commands on myText based on the conditions you set

```
<input my-change-directive type="text ng-model="myText" />

.directive('myChangeDirective',function() {
    return {
        require : 'ngModel',
        link : function($scope,$element,$attrs) {
            var stringTest = function(_string) {
                //test string here, return true
                //if you want to process it
            }
            $element.bind('change',function(e) { 
                if(stringTest($attrs.ngModel) === true) {
                    //make ajax call here
                    //run $scope.$apply() in ajax callback if scope is changed
                }
            });
        }
    }
})
```