# Using ng-model in search filter

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a search filter in table  and I given ng-model name as selectedGcode for it. I am  calling ng-click =viewAccount() inorder to call the function on click. But I am getting $scope.selectedGcode in my controller as undefined.

HTML :

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr class="myheading">
  <th class="col-sm-2"> Code
  </th>
  <th class="col-sm-2">Name
 </th>
 </tr>

  <tr>
   <th class="col-sm-2" >
<input type="text"  class="form-control" ng-model="selectedGcode" placeholder="Search" ng-click="viewAccount()" /></th>
 <th class="col-sm-2" >
<input type="text"  class="form-control"  /></th>
 <tr>

 <tbody>
<tr data-ng-repeat="data in tableData">
        <td  class ="stylethecontent" >{{ data.groupzcode}}</td>
        <td  class ="stylethecontent" >{{data.groupzname}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
 $scope.viewAccount = function(){

   var json = {

  "json": {
    "request": {
      "servicetype": "6",
      "functiontype": "6014",
      "session_id": $rootScope.currentSession,
           "data": {
        "shortname": $scope.selectShortName,
        "groupzcode":$scope.selectedGcode

       }
    }
  }
};

UserService.viewListAccount(json).then(function(response) {

              console.log(json);

             if (response.json.response.statuscode == 0 && response.json.response.statusmessage == 'Success')

               $scope.tableData = response.json.response.data;



        }); 
    };
```

Comment: i dont find anywhere you are using selectedGcode  in controller

Comment: Hi , please check in the request. Edited few mins back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to trigger viewAccount() every time something is typed you should use [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange).

```
<input type="text"  class="form-control" ng-model="selectedGcode" placeholder="Search" ng-change="viewAccount()" /></th>
```

If you want to trigger viewAccount() specifically on a click, you should use a button instead.

```
<input type="text"  class="form-control" ng-model="selectedGcode" placeholder="Search"/></th>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="viewAccount()"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use "ng-model", or "data-ng-model", not just "model="selectedGcode""
And you can use ngKeyup instead of ngClick. Because ngClick will be triggered just when the user will click on the input form and not when it will write something.

Comment: I am sorry , I was using ng-model only. When editing missed it .

Comment: Then the problem is that you are using ngClick which will be fired just once, when you first click on the input. So, as I said earlier, you better use ngKeyup in order to call the function every time the user writes a new letter. Or you can use ngChange with debounce, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22158063/angular-ngchange-variant-when-user-finishes-typing

Comment: Hi , yes its the problem with my ng-click. I figured it out. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'ng-model' instead of 'model' keyword in `<input>` to get the value in controller.

Comment: I am sorry , I was using ng-model only. When editing missed it .

Comment: Use of events like ng-change other than ng-click will solve the problem.