# send data after pause in ng-keyup (Angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use ng-keyup to my angular app for searching data to my backend. But the problem is, it will send request to my server every press. How can I make it send post request to my backend after the user pause/stop typing? Or it's wrong to use ng-keyup for this?

my html

```
<input ng-keyup="search(data)" ng-model="data" type="text"/>
```

controller

```
$scope.search=function($scope, $http){
   ....http post codes here...
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22158063/angular-ngchange-variant-when-user-finishes-typing

Comment: @bobtta based on your requirement you can limit. 1. If your search is based on each characters which user typed means then http call should happen 2. Otherwise count the length of the data and call the service by setting some limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [debounce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions#triggering-and-debouncing-model-updates) option for `ng-model` for this purpose.

Just add `ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }"` in your input will do.

Comment: this work as what i am expecting. coz the answer of @aruna it just let my app wait for 1 sec but still it will query every characters. But with your solution, will just query after 1 second the user pause from typing. It saves me tons of requests to my server. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-change` with `$timeout` as below.

**Note**: `$http` and `$timeout` should be injected in your controller since you used `$http` as parameter in your `search` method above.

```
<input ng-change="search(data)" ng-model="data" type="text"/>
```

JS

```
var handle;
$scope.search = function(data){
   if(handle){
        $timeout.cancel(handle);
        handle  = null;
    }
    handle = $timeout(function(){
       // $http.post(..)
    }, 1000);
};
```