# Format input with euro sign on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, formatting

Using AngularJS, I have an input on an HTML form:

```
<input id="amount" type="number" ng-model="amount">
```

- I want the user to enter something like: 12.3
- But I want the input to show something like that: 12.30 €
- I want this real-time or on blur.
- I also want to keep the possibility to easily perform arithmetic on this input:

  ```
  <!-- multiply by VAT -->
  total: {{ amount * 1.015 }}
  ```

I already had a look at:

- [How to do two-way filtering in angular.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616636/how-to-do-two-way-filtering-in-angular-js) (filtering the content of the scope, but not the content of the input which exactly the opposite of what I want)
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency (not filtering the input, but only the output)

  None of those answer my question.

Here is an empty jsfiddle if needed: http://jsfiddle.net/6V7c2/

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n

Comment: Yes I saw that (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency) but it's not what I need. If you look closely at the example they provide, the input (<input>) is not formatted. Only the output ({{ }}). In my case I could format the total, but not the input string.

Answer (score 0):

Just extending Doug R's solution from [angular directive encapsulating a delay for ng-change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121460/angular-directive-encapsulating-a-delay-for-ng-change) you can make use of the directive based solution.

Thereby after a change in the input element, the required actions take place after a configurable amount of delay.

You can see the same in http://jsfiddle.net/Lrt7e/1/

```
<input ng-model="vars.value" ng-change="updateValue(vars.value)" ng-delay="1000" />
```

Comment: Yes I though about that but you are changing the model here. Thus arithmetic is not possible anymore. Meaning, when you will compute the total:  {{  vars.value * 1.015 }}, once the model is updated with the currency sign, it fails. What I need here is something between the model and it's representation in the HTML.

Comment: Indeed that might do the trick. I don't find that solution elegant though. I'll try to figure out something or see if anyone else as some kind of magic angular directive. Otherwise, I'll go with your solution.