# Javascript w/ Angular: peculiar disparity with string.split() behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get a string turned into an array of strings using `.split(n)`, and normally I have no problem with this, but I am encountering a peculiar behavior with `angular`'s involvement.

I have a model, defined very simply;

```
var _this = $scope;

_this.model = {
    search: {
        value: "",
        run: function() {}
    }
};
```

Then, I have `search.value` bound to an `ng-model` attribute on a text field;

```
<input type="text" id="search-byName"
               placeholder="Search"
               ng-model="model.search.value"
               ng-change="options.search.run()" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 400 }" />
```

Seems simple enough; Before my controller initializes, I create and attach the `run` function.

```
_this.model.search.run = function() {
    console.log('value: ', _this.model.search.value.split(':'));
};
```

So I initialize the controller and everything, then I start to type any text into the textbox. I'm met with a javascript error;

#### TypeError: value.split is not a function

Now here is the interesting part, if I do it just a slight bit differently, it works fine.

```
_this.model.search.run = function() {
    var $value = _this.model.search.value;
    console.log('value: ', $value.split(':'));
};
```

Is there a reason, and a workaround, for this behavior?

Comment: Try doing (_this.model.search.value).split(':'). It may be an order of operations issue.

Comment: That doesn't seem to remedy it, though an order of operations issue does sound likely.

Comment: what does `ng-delay` do?

Comment: It is old, I meant to remove it. It just encapsulates the behavior to slow down the running of the method by a few seconds; You can see the code I used for it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121460/angular-directive-encapsulating-a-delay-for-ng-change

Comment: I updated it to use the new `ng-model-options="{ debounce: 400 }"`.

Comment: then you are getting ahead of `ng-delay` probably and would likely need to use `$timeout`

Comment: create a demo that replicates problem, also note that `ng-model` will nullify model properties when they aren't valid using some validation directives

Comment: are you mean `ng-change="model.search.run()"` here `ng-change="options.search.run()"`? try `ng-change="model.search.run(model.search.value)"`

Comment: Make sure _this.model.search.value is typeof String. Also, is your ng-change supposed to be at options.search.run or model.search.run?

Comment: You were right. I was getting ahead of the delay, and it was firing too early. Changing it to `ng-model-options="{ debounce: 400 }"` fixed the problem! Or ... is that not really fixing it?

Comment: Would you post all that as an official answer so I may credit you?