# How do i delay call a function in ng-init Angular

Tags: angularjs

Currently when the dome reach the line below this function `returnCookie()` is run immediately.

```
<div class="" ng-init="test.name=returnCookie()">
```

I would like to delay it for a few seconds maybe something like this

```
<div class="" ng-init="test.name=Delay(1000,returnCookie())">
```

Delaying 1000ms before executing `returnCookie()`.

> I do note not want to use `$timeout(function() {},1000)` inside of the function, as this function only needs to delay in this case while it's use on other page without needing to delay.

Please assist, Thanks.

Comment: Could you not create a function `delayCookieReturn()` which simply calls `$timeout(returnCookie, 1000)` and set your `ng-init` to that? That way you don't have to alter `returnCookie`.

Comment: you could try to modify the directive provided in this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121460/angular-directive-encapsulating-a-delay-for-ng-change) to use it with ng-init